# Mulesoft how to rollback rest api call

Tags: rest, transactions, mule, saga

I have a mule flow lets say flow X, it calls a external rest api (API 1) to create a user in System B passing a payload from System A. Once user is created in System B, requirement is to insert the user ID from System B along with the user ID from System A(Present in json payload)  to a correlation database table. How can I make these two actions atomic so that correlation table will have correlation record when user is created in System B. We have a mule Rest API that can take Source and target system ids of the user and insert in correlation table.

I do not think we can use XA transaction while dealing with two distributed systems.

we can not use single payload attribute/ or combination of attributes to check whether a user is already created in System B. that's why we have correlation table to correlate users between two systems. I need a pattern that will make sure Correlation table is inserted when a user created in System B.

I read about saga pattern and compensating transaction but do not know how to implement in mule.

Comment: XA is meant for distributed transactional systems, like databases. REST is not transactional, so you can't use XA with REST requests.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that REST API has rollback. But definition of it. It is [Statelessness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

You should provide way to redo work (pseudo transaction) on each level of API calls and do this rollback "manually".